# Cant Run Default ASP.NET Web App In Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Just starting up an ASP.NET project with Visual Studio Code on a Mac

I've been through all the usual steps, ending with the `dnu restore` command which completed successfully.

I then run `dnx web` and I get a running localhost:5000 - but when I browse to that address there is no content.

In the terminal window I can see the error below (sorry I haven't included all of it as it's quite verbose).

```
info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/deanchalk/.local/share/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/  
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method firstmacaspnetapp.Controllers.HomeController.Index with arguments () - ModelState is Valid'
fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.ILibraryExporter' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.ILibraryExporter' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService'.
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite (IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite (System.Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've googled around and cannot find any info.

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-firstmacaspnetapp-88915393-5f54-4e2d-9285-912b92370fb0",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "firstmacaspnetapp"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime":"1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: I had the same error with Visual Studio on Windows. In my case I was accidentally running my project with all the rc1 packages on an rc2 runtime. After switching the runtime it was fine. Maybe you have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Type

> dnvm list

into the terminal when in your project folder. Then check your project.json for all the projects to see if the correct versions are listed for dependencies.

Then run

> dnu restore

That solved it for me on OSX.

Comment: ah man - your idea looked soooooo promising, but when i managed to get everything on the right version, it made no difference at all. Thanks anyway - and if you have any other ideas i'd be grateful - all I want to do is get as asp.net site up on my mac and its proving to be an impossible task

Comment: I **have** it running on my Mac :) Could you check what `dnvm list` returns on your Mac?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201252/dnx-web-error-500-when-try-to-execute @af0l can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this error as well when I was setting up my asp.net project on my Mac. I fixed it by upgrading Mono (if that's the library you are using. Core should be upgraded if you are using that). To upgrade, use this for mono from terminal:

> dnvm upgrade -r mono

Use this to upgrade core from terminal:

> dnvm upgrade -r coreclr

I then ran `dnu restore` just to be sure and then `dnx web` and I was able to pull it up on `http://localhost:5000/`

Note: I made all of the other upgrades first, so this may have been the last problem (if you know what I mean). Worth a shot though, and it worked for me.