# dnx web error 500 when try to execute

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to execute in a Mac (El Capitán), the MusicStore example in ASP.NET from the [official repository.](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore)

I have tested it using mono and core, switching in dnvm, but no results. The dnu build is working fine with mono, with core, the build fails.

When I execute dnx web, all works fine, but when I execute the project (firs load), I have a 500 error, with this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to resolve service for
>   type 'Microsoft.Extensions.CompilationAbstractions.ILibraryExporter'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RoslynCompilationService'.

I have changed all possibilities (Mono and Core), but I have no idea where is the problem... and I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933074/cant-run-default-asp-net-web-app-in-visual-studio-code-for-mac) with no results

**Project JSON Added**

```
{
"authors": [
    "Microsoft"
],
"description": "Music store application on ASP.NET 5",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"compilationOptions": { "warningsAsErrors": true, "define": [ "DEMO", "TESTING" ] },
"compile": [
    "../../shared/**/*.cs"
],
"publishExclude": "*.cmd",
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*"
},
"commands": {
    "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration",
    "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:5003",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004",
    "weblistener": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5002"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.0.10-*"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks!!

**dnvm list (command result) I have tested with Mono and Core...**

[image]

[image: Error executing]

Comment: Have you run `dnu restore`?

Comment: Please put here your project.json.

Comment: If you use dev branch Music Store then switch to RC1 - git checkout tags/1.0.0-rc1 and dnu restore

Comment: @Boyarincev I have added project.json, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Ensure to get the [rc1 version of the Music Store](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/1.0.0-rc1)

The main process to making the application work once everything is working is to make sure that your runtime is on the latest version of the feed (in this case, Nuget.org).

Nuget.org at the moment is at `rc1-final`. So you'll need the `rc1-final`/`rc1-update1` to run it properly. (Which is ok for you)

Once this is done, we're ready to restore packages for the application.

- `dnu restore` for the DNX runtime

And in other scenarios (not the MusicStore in this case), you'll need to run `npm install` and `bower install`.

Once everything is updated, you can run `dnx web` at the same level as the `project.json` and it should run.

Comment: My Canadian pleasure. :)